# reading data from sysfs

Tags: drivers, sysfs

I am trying to provide DMA via PCI. For that purpose I have an example of sysfs driver. I succesfully stored data to RAM but unfortunately I cant read them. I have a functions store_dmaread and show_dmaread. I acces them via c code like this. The write function works fine but the show function which I open via read() works (reads the DMA data, prints them) but the user space buffer is not visible in that function.

```
char buf[2] = {3,3};
fw = open("/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/dmaread", O_RDWR);
read (fw,buf, 2);
write (fw, buf, 2);
close(fw);
```

the function in the driver looks like this:

```
static ssize_t show_dmaread(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    printk("User space buffer value %d \n", buf[0]) // PRINTS 0
    // MORE CODE WHICH WORKS
}
static ssize_t store_dmaread(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count)
{
    // WORKS FINE THE ATTRIBUTE CHANGES ITS VALUE
}
```

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it appears you are expecting that the `char * buf` passed to your `show_dmaread` function points directly to the userspace buffer passed to `read` (or at the very least has been populated with the data in the user-side buffer):

However, looking in [Documentation/filesystem/sysfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt) it says:

> sysfs allocates a buffer of size (PAGE_SIZE) and passes it to the
> method. Sysfs will call the method exactly once for each read or
> write. This forces the following behavior on the method
> implementations:
>
> - On read(2), the show() method should fill the entire buffer.   Recall that an attribute should only be exporting one value, or an
>   array of similar values, so this shouldn't be that expensive.
>
>   This allows userspace to do partial reads and forward seeks
>   arbitrarily over the entire file at will. If userspace seeks back to
>   zero or does a pread(2) with an offset of '0' the show() method will
>   be called again, rearmed, to fill the buffer.

Which leads me to believe you are getting a newly allocated buffer and that some other kernel code manages copying your buffer back over to userspace.

Comment: Thank you very much I understand now but still I cannot access the buffer which is automatically allocated. I can access it in the function show fill it and print its values but after show functions finishes I cannot find any solution how to access it in user space.